# Determine the domain of the function $g(x, y, z)=\ln(16-4x^2-4y^2-z^2)$.

Tags: functions

By the condition of the logarithm, we have:
\begin{align*}
     16-4x^2-4y^2-z^2                           &> 0 \\
     4x^2+4y^2+z^2                              &<16 \\
     \frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{z^2}{16} &< 1
\end{align*}
Therefore the domain of $ g $ is the interior of an origin-centered ellipsoid.

I think this is the correct solution, I await your comments. If anyone has a different solution or correction of my work I will be grateful.

Comment: I think that's fine.

Comment: Yes, your solution is perfectly fine and contains all possible solutions.